# Is this the best approach when using linq with a nested loop?

Tags: linq

I have a list of items 'ActiveNodes'. Each item belongs to a 'tier' and so has a tierID. TierID is not unique. What I want to do is loop though all items by tier and then each item within the tier. This is how I've approached it, but given the flexibility of linq , I wondered if there was any better approach.

```
        var tiers = ActiveNodes.Select(x => x.TierID).Distinct();

        foreach (var t in tiers)
        {
            var nodes = ActiveNodes.Where(x => x.TierID == t);

            foreach(var n in nodes)
            {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `GroupBy`:

```
var tiers = ActiveNodes.GroupBy(x => x.TierID);

foreach (var t in tiers)
{
    // Id for current group can be taken from t.Key property
    var tierId = t.Key;

    // t implements IEnumerable<Node>, so you can loop over it directly
    foreach(var n in t)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```